# Prove that the sequence converges using ε−N

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

The sequence:  
$\{{\frac{cos(n^2)}{n^2−2}}\} $
I tried:
${|\frac{cos(n^2)}{n^2−2}|} $≤ ${|\frac{1}{n^2−2}|} $<${|\frac{1}{N^2−2}|} $
If I remove the -2, the denominator becomes larger. Also, ${N^2−2} $ may not be greater than zero, so how would one remove the absolute value?

Comment: What if you take then the maximum in between say $N=2$ and the solution for the inequality $\frac{1}{N^2-2}<\epsilon$? assuming $N>2.$ At the end of the day you need an $N.$

Comment: For large $N$, (minimally, $N = 2$), $N^2 - 2 < N^2$. Note that you are allowed to make N as large as you want, when proving convergence.